How to change ZSH prompt in zprofile?
The default prompt in Mac OS ZSH Terminal looks like alex@alexs-MacBook-Pro /Users %
If i execute PROMPT="%1~> " it changed to /Users>
But when I add PROMPT="%1~> " or export PROMPT="%1~> " to ~/.zprofile it has no effect.
P.S. If possible I would like to avoid using any extra file like .zshrc and use just the profile.

Commands in .zprofile are executed at login, not at start of new subshell.

@YuriGinsburg no, I added echo hi and I can see in new terminal it's being executed. Also, the brew added its initialisation command to zprofile so I suppose it's the standard way of configuring ZSH

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

What's the point? .zprofile is for all login shells (interactive and non-interactive ones). You most likely don't need a prompt definition in a non-interactive shell. But if you really want to do it this way, you must make sure to start the shell as a login shell (option -l).

macOS terminals usually default to starting a login shell for each new window because the terminal itself doesn't have a shell as a parent process. That said, .zshrc is still the more appropriate place for defining the prompt, as the prompt is only used by interactive shells that source .zshrc on startup.
